# ASP .NET MVC Error in executing search between dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]

Help me fix this error.

[image]

When 1st load with no value of the date to and date from, it works.
But when the date to and from **has** value the error show note: Nullable dateTime to in the DB.

Thanks.

Comment: It's better to copy/paste code and logs instead of posting images. Some advices to post here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post more code. There are few things here that can be wrong. Post the model you are using and structure of database table you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line where you are getting error:

```
var report = db.qryItemsMR_emp.Where(m => m.DepartmentShortname==Search && (DateTime?)m.mr_date >= fromd && (DateTime?)m.mr_date <= tod).List();
```

Compairing Nullable DateTime to Datetime generates error when Nullable has value.

**OR**

alternatively write two different check when `fromd.HasValue` and `tod.HasValue` or second when for nullable like :

```
if(fromd.HasValue && tod.HasValue )
    var report = db.qryItemsMR_emp.Where(m => m.DepartmentShortname==Search && m.mr_date >= fromd.Value && m.mr_date <= tod.Value).List();
else
    var report = db.qryItemsMR_emp.Where(m => m.DepartmentShortname==Search).List();
```

You will need to declare `report` outside if & else with static type instead of `var` to use later. I am not sure what is type of return so left that to you.